# How will i integrate POS System in PHP to Touchscreen Monitor?

Tags: php, point-of-sale

I want to create a Point of Sales System with Inventory System that generates Balance Sheet and Income Statement.

- How can I integrate my system to a touch screen monitor?
- Do i need a touchscreen monitor before I will start the system or it is alright after I create the system?
- What will i do to print in a thermal printer using PHP?

Comment: I think you need to do mounds of research before getting into the POS field, firstly. There are things to consider like PCI, uptime, etc. Secondly, touchscreens would act just as if it was a normal monitor, except when you click, it is the mouse. Thirdly, printers have nothing to do with PHP, at all.

Answer (score 7):

The touch screen monitor will replace the need for a mouse and keyboard, which in turn means that you don't need to do anything in over to get that working, except for not using hover-things in your markup since most users will tap instead of move the finger over the link.

In order to print on a thermal printer you need some form of component, I'd recommend either looking at some ActiveX-component like rawdataprinter OR a free open source Java Applet like jZebra (found here http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) which will help you send raw data to the thermal printer. Apart from this, you'll need to learn the printers language if you're not already know it. For Zebra you'd want to look at ZPL/ZPL II, for Intermec IPL or Direct Protocol, etc etc.

I've been working quite a lot with thermal printing from web and it's a bit of a hassle, but if you get it working it's usually a helpful tool for POS, TA, TMS, WMS and similar solutions.

Good luck. :)

Comment: +1 for interpreting the english-challenged authors intent, and then providing a useful answer.